# How to create a 1/255 f32 vector using neon?

Tags: arm, neon

When I calculate alpha blending, I need to convert 8bit alpha to float, which would be alpha/255. Because NEON doesn't have divide, I want to alpha * 1/255. So how can I generate 1/255 vector in q1?

vmov.f32 q1, #0.003921569  always reports an error.

vmov.u32 q1, #255
vrecpe.u32 q1, q1  always generates 0 in f32.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you have 8 bit data, you don't want to convert to float to do alpha blending; you can get sufficient precision using 16-bit fixed-point arithmetic which lets you keep more pixels in each vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close. You need to convert the vector of 255 to a float before taking the reciprocal.

```
vmov.u32        q0, #255
vcvt.f32.u32    q0, q0
vrecpe.f32      q1, q0
```

Be advised that `vrecpe` has a small amount of error, but it should be close enough for alpha blending.

Answer (score 2):

You really needn't bother with floating-point for a trivial alpha blend.  Given:

```
y = rint(x * a / 255.0);
```

You can get the same result for any 8-bit inputs without floating-point using:

```
t = x * a;
t += (t + 0x80) >> 8;
y = (t + 0x80) >> 8;
```

Which is something like:

```
; given eight 8-bit x in d0, and eight 8-bit a in d1
    vmull.u8 q2, d0, d1
    vrsra.u16 q2, q2, #8
    vrshrn.u16 d2, q2, #8
; result is eight 8-bit (s*a/255) in d2
```

Generally the last two operations implement a well-rounded divide by 255 from a 16-bit input to an 8-bit output; but they rely on the limited range of an 8-by-8 multiply.  If the 16-bit intermediate is more than just the result of a multiply then it may be necessary to clamp, and since there's no `vqrsra` the sequence gets longer:

```
; given eight 8-bit x in d0, and eight 8-bit a in d1
    vmull.u8 q2, d0, d1
    ???
    vrshr.u16 q3, q2, #8
    vqadd.u16 q2, q2, q3
    vqrshrn.u16 d2, q2, #8
; result is eight 8-bit (s*a/255) in d2
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a 100% answer, but since you didn't get any others so far I thought I'd help you get started;

From what I remember, the subset of floats you can load using `vmov.f32` is very limited, so if you want to load an arbitrary float, you need to store it as a constant and load it from the constant pool using `vldr`. Something like this should do it;

```
ldr r1,=floats 

vldr.32 s0,[r1]     @1/256

floats:
.float 0.003921569
```

The "not 100%" part is that I've not looked into the vector instructions so I'm unsure if you can substitute `s0` right away with `q1` in this code or if you need to move `s0` to `q1` after loading.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, neon can also load constant. The asm code is embedded in C, so I can also calculate float constant in c. but neon can not move register like r0 to Q0/S0, right? Maybe I have to pass the constant to a variable and pass variable address to embedded asm code.

Comment: @RichardZhao: of course you can move from r0 to s0.  `vmov s0, r0`.  You can also load a precomputed constant directly to `s0` or `q0`, which is probably what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

probably you want
float32x4_t x = vdupq_n_32(1.0f / 255);

the compiler takes care to compute the constant, the vdup instruction broadcasts the value to all four lanes of a vector

the vdup instruction supports NEON scalars and ARM registers as source operand